# ServiceHost only supports class service types

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, wcf-rest

I have a service named WcfService2 (original i know) which has an IService.cs file with a public interface:

```
namespace WcfService2
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {    
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{value}")]
        string GetData(string value);            
    }
}
```

I then have my public class Service1.svc.cs file which returns a string for the value like so:

```
namespace WcfService2
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to host this service with a console app like so:

```
namespace Host
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            WebServiceHost host =
            new WebServiceHost(typeof(IService1));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1),
            binding,
            "http://localhost:8000/Hello");
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("I DONT LIKE REST!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <RETURN> to KILL REST FOR GOOD");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error after I run it:

> ServiceHost only supports class service types.

So this obviously relates to my IService being of public interface type. But I dont know how else to create it, when I first created the `WCF Service application` it gives you the two standard files IService and Service.svc files if I delete either or, and only Implement this solution in one class when I try to add the web service in local soultion nothing is found.

Is there a way to fiddle with the host code?

Comment: There is another answer to try @ http://stackoverflow.com/q/19306395/16391

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I suggest that you change this:

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(IService1));
```

to this:

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
```

Comment: I get this error if I do that: `The contract type WcfService2.Service1 is not attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.  In order to define a valid contract, the specified type (either contract interface or service class) must be attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.`

Comment: @Garrith: You shouldn't get that first error with the code posted. Your ramblings about deleting files may play a part in this.

Comment: Anyone who reads this answer please also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864006/servicecontractattribute-error-on-simple-wcf-service Becareful as WebServiceHost is Service1 and AddServiceEndpoint is IService1!

Comment: how this can be an answer? It causes `contract type WcfService2.Service1 is not attributed with ServiceContractAttribute` error like @GarrithGraham said

Answer (score 4):

You should create the WebServiceHost with the class implementing the service;

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx) for an example.

Comment: please see reply under Will Marcouliers answer.